# Find double qoutes inside a string which is in double quotes in mysql

Tags: mysql, php

I'm storing a string that includes, by necessity, double quotes, e.g.:

```
ID           Data
1   "This is "my" example." 
2   "This is my example."
```

I want to find only those row which are like ID 1. How can i do this.

"This is "my" example." (I know it's hard to tell the difference here)

Please suggest.

Comment: I just posted an answer, but I just realised from your tags I'm not clear if you specifically need PHP or just the SQL statement

Comment: To clarify: how many double quotes are in the data for rows 1 and 2? 4 and 2, or 2 and 0? In other words, are the double quotes surrounding each string a part of the data? To clarify further: are you looking for strings that include double quotes, or strings that have double quotes that are not the first and last characters of the string?

Comment: What RDFozz asked. Please clarify and we can reopen.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table
where data like '"%"%"'
```

Or you could compare the length of data against the length of data when '"' is replaced with an empty string ('').